# How to create simple distribution chart of random numbers in a range (java or javascript)

Tags: javascript, java, charts, distribution

In my simple app i often choose a random number within a given range (0..~500000). I need a simple way to visualize the distribution in a browser. So output options are png, html/js, svg, ascii? .

The data is stored in a simple map (guava's [AtomicLongMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.html)) index->count. I don't need any options. I only want to see the rough quality of ditribution. A tool specialized to visualize distribution that could be directly fed with the map (or map serialized to json) would the best option.
In json the data would look like this

```
{
   "0":6
   "1":3
   "2":4
   "3":0
   "4":2
}
```

(for a range [0..4])

I got first look at jfreechart and google chart for both i have to convert my map to a special data format and i have to provide labels (i don't need any labels). Some years ago i worked with Birt but this is also very complicated/ overkill for my simple requirement.

Comment: i thought i described the problem: i have a map and want to visualize it. and i don't want to convert the data or give additional data. - updated the question heading

Comment: added code of data format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be to create an image and draw for each column a line with height of each random number. A simple java code would look like this.

```
final int AmountNumbers = 1000;
final int MaxSize = 500000;

// create Random Numbers
Random rnd = new Random();
ArrayList<Integer> randomNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < AmountNumbers; i++)
    randomNumbers.add(rnd.nextInt(MaxSize));

// create picture
int width = AmountNumbers, height = 200;    
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D ig2 = bi.createGraphics();
ig2.setPaint(Color.red);

// draw lines for every number
for(int i = 0; i < AmountNumbers; i++){
    int rndNumber = randomNumbers.get(i);
    ig2.drawLine( i, rndNumber * height / MaxSize, i,  height); 
}

// save as png
ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", new File("chart.PNG"));
```

Comment: that's really simple thanks. But how to properly scale it: in my case the width is about 500000 pixels.

Comment: Since you cannot scale smaller than one pixel you could draw every hundredth or thousandth value. That depends on what you want to point out in your chart. Sounds like a complete different question to me: How to draw meaningful random number distribution charts for lots of numbers?

Comment: i really like this simple approach, implementing the scaling will take some time. and probably later i will add a label. I will accept the answer later today (i fear if it is accepted now i will  not see other answers).